# I am trying to figure out why my string won't concatenate

Tags: python

I am trying to print out the phrase variable to the terminal using multiple strings. I am trying to replace one string with another string.

I don't know what to try to make sure the code will concatenate.

```
firstName = "jason", "jennifer"
LastName = "Maraz", "Lopez"
actor = firstName[0], LastName[0]
actress = firstName[1], LastName[1]
introduceActor= "hi my name is ".join(actor)


print (actor, actress)
s = "lucky"
t = "happy", "greatful", "nice"
phrase = "I am so " + str(s) + " see " + actor + " today. I am as " + str(s) + " as could be"
phrase = phrase.replace(str(s), str(t[1]))  
phrase2 = introduceActor

print(phrase)
print(phrase2)
index = phrase.find("i")
print(index)
```

the error I got was:

```
  File "/Users/zachary/Documents/code proejcts/Test.py", line 11, in <module>
    phrase = "I am so " + str(s) + " see " + actor + " today. I am as " + str(s) + " as could be"
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str
```

Comment: Becuse it's not a string, it's a tuple. Read the error message!

Comment: I'm still trying to learn Python what is a tuple?

Comment: @ZacharyBlumstein A tuple is a combination of multiple values, similar to a list.  e.g. `(1, 2)` or `('a', 'b', 'c')`.  When you say `actor = firstName[0], LastName[0]`, `actor` is a 2-tuple.

Comment: See https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: @ox5653 `actor = "Jason Maraz"
actress = "Jenifer Lopez"`

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python string tutorial", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 1):

Your "actor" and "actress" are tuples that hold 2 strings each.

For your purpose, you should probably use:

```
actor = firstName[0] + LastName[0]
actress = firstName[1] + LastName[1]
```

That way, you will have strings instead of tuples. [Check here for more information](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python)

Comment: Those variables are tuples, *not* arrays.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not used to working with Python. I'll edit my answer